# How can I count the number of occurrences of a given string in a string array in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to see which tags occur most frequently in my dataset. When i try to do this on my own i get something like this:

```
df['tags'].value_counts()
```

> ['Startup']  80
> ['Bitcoin']   79
> ['The Daily Pick']  78
> ['Addiction', 'Health', 'Body', 'Alcohol', 'Mental Health'] 62

Some articles have many tags but
I would like to count the tracking count for each tag separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You need to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas.Series.explode), and then use [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

res = df['tags'].apply(literal_eval).explode().value_counts()
print(res)
```

Output:

```
Startup      4
Bitcoin      3
Addiction    2
Health       2
Name: tags, dtype: int64
```

Sample input DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "tags" : [
        "['Startup']", "['Startup']", "['Startup']", "['Startup']",
        "['Bitcoin']", "['Bitcoin']", "['Bitcoin']", 
        "['Addiction', 'Health']", "['Addiction', 'Health']"
    ]
})
```

By thanks @ljmc:

*NB. `ast.literal_eval` is not safe always. from [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval:%7E:text=This%20function%20had,thus%20not%20recommended.):*

> This function had been documented as “safe” in the past without defining what that meant. That was misleading. This is specifically designed not to execute Python code, unlike the more general eval(). [...] But it is not free from attack: A relatively small input can lead to memory exhaustion or to C stack exhaustion, crashing the process. There is also the possibility for excessive CPU consumption denial of service on some inputs. Calling it on untrusted data is thus not recommended.

Comment: You should probably add a warning that `literal_eval` creates an opening for code injection and should not be used with untrusted input.

Comment: Also from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval): "This function had been documented as “safe” in the past without defining what that meant. That was misleading. This is specifically designed not to execute Python code, unlike the more general eval(). [...] But it is not free from attack: A relatively small input can lead to memory exhaustion or to C stack exhaustion, crashing the process. There is also the possibility for excessive CPU consumption denial of service on some inputs. Calling it on untrusted data is thus not recommended."

Comment: @ljmc, thanks, I didn't read that before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) or [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) to your series.

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "tags": [['Startup'], ["Bitcoin"], ["Startup", "Ethereum"]]
})

c = Counter()
df["tags"].apply(c.update)
```

`c` contains

```py
Counter({'Startup': 2, 'Bitcoin': 1, 'Ethereum': 1})
```

Comment: Can you write `df['tags'].value_counts()` on your `dataframe`?

Comment: Hey for this code when i print c i get count but for each character in df

Comment: @IvonaK I guess your `df` tags contains a serialised list, not actual lists.

Comment: @I'mahdi I can, it's just 1, 1, 1 for each value.

Comment: it is pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: @IvonaK I meant the contents of each cell, if its strings that look like lists, you need to evaluate or deserialise them first, then you can use the "apply-counter" or the `explode` + `value_counts` method.